# 2 level deep relation in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**The Problem**

I'm working with a 2-level deep relation of ActiveRecord classes in rails. I have three classes `foo`, `bar` and `bla`. `foo` has many `bar`'s, and `bar` has one `bla`

All my relations are working fine individually, that is, anything like `Foo.find(1).bars.find(1).blas` works fine. The issue is that given a `foo`, I'd like to get the ActiveRecord set of all `bla`'s related to `foo`'s `bars`.

**Things I've Tried**

Combining `bar` and `bla` into one table: This is obviously a solution, but I normalized out `bla` for performance reasons as I need to call `Foo.find(1).bars` a lot, but only rarely need `bla`.

`Foo.find(1).bars.blas`: The `blas` method simply doesn't exist here

`Foo.find(1).bars.map{|b| b.bla}`: This is the best workaround I've found so far. However, the result of the mapping is an array, so I wouldn't be able to apply ActiveRecord methods to the set later on (which is the goal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup `has_many` with `through` option.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :blas, through: :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  has_one :bla
end

class Bla < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

After that you can get all `bla`s associated with given `Foo` instance like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> Foo.last.blas  
=> <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [...]
```

See [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for details.

Comment: and call Foo.find(1).blas

Answer (score 0):

You can do `has_many  :blas, :through => :bars` within Foo.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association